# How to randomly display textarea items

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, jsx

I have 4 textarea items that I want to display but I want the order of them displayed to be random. I have these items but I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

```
<div>
    <textarea>text 1</textarea>
    <textarea>text 2</textarea>
    <textarea>text 3</textarea>
    <textarea>text 4</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Shuffle sort
let shuffleSort = () => (0.5 - Math.random());

// Get your textareas
let txtAreas = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.container textarea'))

// Define a few grid areas
let styles = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

// Shuffle textareas and add the styles in order by index
txtAreas.sort(shuffleSort).forEach((textarea, i) => {
  textarea.classList.add(styles[i])
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "one" "two" "three" "four";
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea>1</textarea>
  <textarea>2</textarea>
  <textarea>3</textarea>
  <textarea>4</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank! This was simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

First, set four variables randomly, then use document.write, or, better,  set document.getElementById('output').innerHTML to the textarea with the text variables.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get children of main and prepare an array with their values

let x = $("#main").children();
let beginArr = [];
for (let y = 0; y < x.length; ++y) {
  beginArr.push(y);
}

// Shuffle sort and create a new array
let finalArr = [];
let y = 0;
do {
  let z = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x.length - y));
  finalArr.push(beginArr[z]);
  beginArr.splice(z, 1);  
  y++;
} while (y < x.length);

// Rearrange the output
let domElem = '';
for (let y = 0; y < finalArr.length; ++y) {
 domElem += x[finalArr[y]].outerHTML;
}

$("#main").html('');
$("#main").append(domElem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <textarea>1</textarea>
  <textarea>2</textarea>
  <textarea>3</textarea>
  <textarea>4</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you had React in your tag so I made a quick React example. There's no state management, so it's a bit incomplete, but hopefully you'll get the idea.

```js
class TextArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
      text: props.text || ''
    }
  }
  
  change = (e) => {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value})
  }
  
  render() {
    return <textarea onChange={this.change} value={this.state.text} />
  }
}

class TextAreas extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      data: [
        {key: 1, text: 'text 1'},
        {key: 2, text: 'text 2'},
        {key: 3, text: 'text 3'},
        {key: 4, text: 'text 4'}
      ]}
  }
  
  shuffle = () => {
    this.setState({data: _.shuffle(this.state.data)})
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.state.data.map(txt => 
        <TextArea key={txt.key} text={txt.text} />
      )}
      <button onClick={this.shuffle}>Shuffle</button>
      </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TextAreas/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

The concept that the other guys have responded with is correct: just shuffle a JS array and use that to generate the DOM.